# firebase: Filtering data based on user authorization

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm working on firebase with angular js.  I have a data .

```
{menu:[
{access:'all',mnu:'home',href:'admin/home'},
{access:'all',mnu:'view',href:'admin/view},
{access:'admin',mnu:'view',href:'admin/admin}
]
}
```

Kindly help me to wriate rule. if user 'A' requested the menu object it fecth all the objects in menu object. 
if user 'B' requested the menu data it should not fetch data where access='admin'

Thanks & Regards
Ramesh

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. There is good [documentation on the Firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) on [securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) and there are a lot of questions dealing with user-based security already. What have you tried? And where are you stuck?

Comment: In general your title raises a red-flag: you cannot use security rules to filter data. See the [section named "rules are not filters" in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) and the many [questions mentioning the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-security%5d%20rules%20are%20not%20filters).